# mybatis stored proc not getting committed

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I am calling a mysql stored proc through mybatis. But my proc is not getting committed in sql server and was locking tables. I have written in the code to autocommit the JDBC call. Could someone help me to solve this.

```
This below is the xml code to call proc:
<select id="getContactUpdated" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType=" xxx ">
    { call [cia-reporting].dbo.reports_ReturnRoiReports(                
                #{custom1},
                #{custom2},
                #{custom3}
)}`enter code here`

Java code:
    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
    {
        try {
            mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(xxx.class);
            sqlSession.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you require any more info on this.
Thanks,
Shilpa.

Comment: does your procedure update smth? if you just select, you dont need to commit. if you update smth, you need to use <update id="" ... > in your mybatis code

Comment: My proc returns a data table with the input parameters supplied. It does not update anything in db.